# Sql Order by multiple fields in different order

Tags: sql

Hi I have the table below...

```
FirstNumber SecondNumber
    3            2
    2            5
    9            0
    1            4
    8            7
    2            2
    1            4
```

If I use this SQL statement...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY FirstNumber,SecondNumber;
```

I should have the data shown below...This orders the number by FirstNumber, in case of duplicates, it orders the rows by SecondNumber in ASCENDING order since by default it is...

```
FirstNumber SecondNumber
    1            4
    1            4
    2            2
    2            5
    3            2
    8            7
    9            0
```

However, I want to achieve a different ordering. I want to have ordering by FirstNumber in ASCENDING, in case of duplicates, I want them ordered by DESCENDING SecondNumber. How do I do this? So basically I want to have the data below...

```
FirstNumber SecondNumber
    1            4
    1            4
    2            5
    2            2
    3            2
    8            7
    9            0
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: `ORDER BY FirstNumber, SecondNumber DESC` -- that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY FirstNumber,SecondNumber DESC;
```

From [SQL ORDER BY Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

> The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more
>   columns.   The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order
>   by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the
>   DESC keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems this code will do

```
  SELECT *
    FROM Table
ORDER BY FirstNumber asc,   -- <- ascending
         SecondNumber desc  -- <- descending
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        coloumn1 ASC, coloumn2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *

From Table

Order By FirstNumber, SecondNumber desc;
```

This will get you your desired output.